# Find all unread emails System.Net.Mail C#

Tags: c#, smtpclient, system.net.mail

I'm creating a small application where it will find all unread emails and respond to these emails automatically. I want to be able to find all unread emails and I'm not sure how I would do this. I know I need a foreach loop but I can't find a property to find all unread emails. I'm using Net.Mail.

My code is as fallows

```
try
{
    SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");

    // set smtp-client with basicAuthentication
    mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    System.Net.NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new
        System.Net.NetworkCredential("example@live.com", "password");
    mySmtpClient.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;
    mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

    // add from,to mailaddresses
    MailAddress from = new MailAddress("example@live.com");
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress("example@example.eu");
    MailMessage myMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);
    MailMessage msg; 

    // set subject and encoding
    myMail.Subject = "Test message";
    myMail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    // set body-message and encoding
    myMail.Body = "<b>Test Mail</b><br>using <b>HTML</b>.";
    myMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    // text or html
    myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    mySmtpClient.Send(myMail);
}

catch (SmtpException ex)
{
    throw new ApplicationException
        ("SmtpException has occured: " + ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: SMTP is for sending email only. You probably need to connect to POP or IMAP.

Comment: I would use IMAP and check the Read flag to avoid POP deleting the email once retreived. Never try to use SMTP to read emails as @stuartd points out.

Comment: 1) Never do `throw ex` when `ex` is the exception you just caught. You lose the stacktrace. Instead, do `throw;` 2) If you're going to create a new exception in your catch block, it's probably a good idea to put the caught exception into the new exception you're throwing as the `InnerException` 3) Don't catch an exception if you don't plan to log it, or do something about it, or put it in an inner exception.

Comment: It's like going to the pub and trying to sell beer